# Give name to each looped div

Tags: jquery, html, css, while-loop

I have a page to show multiple images(cp-thumb) and when hover the div contains information(cp-hover) with show above the image. I show the image from directories by looping.

So when when mouseover, the hover effect show in all divs but not only the pointed div.

It is because the divs(cp-thumb) have same name since they are looped.

How do I give name of each div which i get from looping?

this is how i loop my div:

```
$dir = dir("images");
while($filename=$dir->read())
```

div html/php:

```
<div class="cp-thumb"><div class="cp-hover" style="display: none;">
<div class="cpHover-bg"></div>
<div class="cpHover-info"><p class="text11">03/09/2013 11:08 AM</p>
<p class="text10">#galaxy #nails</p></div></div>
<img src="images/225cd24c144611e3b69022000a1deb4b_7.jpg" class="img_235x235">
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
<script>
$('.cp-thumb').hover(function () {
    $(this).children('.cp-hover').show();
    },function () {
    $(this).children('.cp-hover').hide();
    });
</script>
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Can you please add the code to `jsFiddle` and share the link?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zEJVK/5/ it works fine in jsfiddle, but in my own code, when i mouseover 1 div, all divs change colour

Comment: Look at the markup generated by your loop. You'll probably find you're missing a closing `div` or something like that, the code is sound.

Comment: As you said , the jsfiddle works good. (1) Check out your code as @billyonecan suggested. (2) Check that there are no css or js scripts that overwrite.